# Good examples of PHP code for an intermediate PHPer?

Tags: php

I know the basics for PHP and have written a school project in PHP (although looking back on it, I'd really love to rewrite it)

I'd really like to get a feel for how to code *good* PHP code though, for example what are the best practices when it comes to PHP? And are there recommended ways of tackling certain tasks?

I think the best way for me to tackle this question would just be for me to spend some time browsing through some PHP code, although I realise there are questions similar to this already the answers mostly seem to reference PHP programs like wordpress . . . which is just a little over my head (not to mention incredibly large to trawl through and try and understand)

So can anybody recommend some programs for me to look at, that promote best practises, but are simple enough for me to understand (i.e. not Wordpress, Magento, or something on that level)?

Comment: not really a S.O type of question.

Comment: Wordpress is anything but a staple of good PHP design.

Comment: Pick an open source framework (Zend, Symfony, ...) and rewrite that school project - learning by doing will teach you much more than just browsing some source code.

Comment: Lurk on SO. It's a great way to pick up on some good practices.

Comment: Lurk on SO. It's a great way to pick up on some bad practices and learn to not code like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you talk about coding style, there are several more or less well-known guidelines, for example

- at the PEAR project http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php
- at the Zend project http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html
- for Drupal developers http://drupal.org/coding-standards
- for Wordpress developers http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#PHP

As you'll find out they differ a lot as it is a matter of taste.

If you want some examples on how to structure a big application in PHP the differences are even bigger, nearly every developer and every project has its very own style of doing things – which actually is a big downside of PHP.

I, personally, do not learn a lot from browsing source code, in my opinion it is better to just start projects and to find out how you can do things the best and google a lot every time you have a problem – this way you'll see a lot of good and bad PHP code and some day you will be able to differ between good and bad code automatically. I don't really know a small PHP application with good coding standards (In general, only BIG or self-written applications come to my mind if I think about PHP. Or ones I never looked into the source code.)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, guess this just needs to be a bit of a birth of fire.

Comment: Have fun and feel free to ask specific questions if you run into problems and are unable to solve them with google :)

Comment: Sure thing :) 

I think the problem for me is acceptance that different developers have varying styles of doing things rather than a unified method for trying to complete thing. I guess it's just something I'll have to live with though!